# How to remove all double spaces from the text

Tags: javascript

I'm struggeling a bit with my homework. In one task we have to correct a text. We have to remove multiple spaces from the text and turn that into one space. And if there is the space at the beginning or at the end we have to do the same. I have created this function:

```
function clean(word) {
  var output = "";
  for (var x = 0; x < word.length; x++)
  {
      if (word.charAt(x) !== " " || word.charAt(x + 1) !== " ") {
        output = output + word.charAt(x);
      }
  }

  return output;
}
console.log("test = " + clean(" test  word  testing   more"));
```

This works for all the spaces in the text but not at the begionning and end. Also it would be better if I do not use the number of the character directly (x) but I can do it if I don't find another way...

Comment: You can always use a regex, `/\s+/g` will match any 1 or more whitespace characters in a row (this will catch things like tabs too), there's also the [String.prototype.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) to remove any trailing whitespace (beginning and end of string)

Comment: I would use a regular expression too but the real issue is that you are changing the size of your array without changing x accordingly.  Typically when you are taking action that changes the size of the array, start at the end and work backwards.

Comment: @Bindrid which array do you mean ? word ?

Comment: no, never mind, I was not looking at the code closely enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use **[`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)**:

```js
function clean(str) {
  // remove double spaces
  while (str.indexOf("  ") > -1) { 
    str = str.replace("  ", " ");
  }

  // remove spaces in the beginning and end (it is called "trim")
  return str.trim(); 
}

console.log(clean(" This is    the    text  with double   spaces!  "));
```

This can be solved in many other ways like using regular expression, but I have decided to demonstrate the easiest and understandable solution.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly simpler replace:

```js
var str = 'a  test string   with multiple      extra  spaces'
console.log(str.replace(/  +/g, ' '));
```

This is leveraging something called regular expressions (Often referred to as regex) - which is basically pattern matching.

This code `/  +/g` is saying [a space][1 or more spaces], with the `g` flag meaning "match all". The 2 slashes are the shorthand method for saying "this is a regular expressions".

Comment: @ChloeCodes Regular expressions are an integral part of most modern day scripting languages. They may not be part of your syllabus but I urge you to make an effort to learn them. There have been countless times through my career where they were the fastest (in terms of both development and execution time) solution to a problem.

Comment: ok thank you :-) i looked into it and we discussed it in calss as well. so this was actually very good from what they suggested too :-) thank you